# I am Getting "fatal: repository not found" when "git clone" a URL

Tags: git, github

[image: Picture]

[image: Error description]

I have tried different methods like credentials manager but there is no login info available.

I tried different methods mentioned above and tried to reinstall git bash as well as recreate a new
repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong address for the repository: it should be https://github.com/ddsy123/cousera-dds instead.

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is wrong,

- The GitHub URL should start with `https://github.com`
- Open your GitHub repository and copy the URL as described below

[image]